# How to align two tables with headers such that same headers come under single column in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone please help me with aligning the two tables such that the same table headers come on the single column? Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roqPX.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it in Powershell.

You need [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0)

Also you need to have the two tables on separate worksheets.

After this you can run the following line in Powershell:

```
Join-Worksheet -Path input.xlsx -WorksheetName Sheet3
```

This will create a new sheet with the name 'Sheet3' like this:

[image]